# Where do we have score in flags tab?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

Where has the score box gone? I'd bet it was there before few hours in [flags tab](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=flags&daterange=).

http://phpcode.eu/images/1320674794.png

<sup>Also, the arrow wasn't there as far as I remember, yes, I can click it to see more details <sup>(score)</sup>, but that's not as simple as it was</sup>

Comment: You asked where it went, answered yourself on the next line, and then tagged this [bug]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is now available in the expanded view, along with the ability to vote, comment, edit, etc. In most cases, you don't need to see the score to know that it is a bad post, of course.